# iOS Share Extension Grabbing URL in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions

I'm trying to create an iOS share extension in swift. When the user is in safari and opens the share extension, I want to be able to grab the URL and use it in my app. I know I can put the code below in the didSelectPost() function in the ShareViewController to get the text that the user enters in the share extension, but how do I get the URL of the web page the user is on when they click the share extension? I'm fairly new to iOS extensions, so any help would be much appreciated.

```
 let shareDefaults = NSUserDefaults(suiteName: "groupName")
 shareDefaults?.setObject(self.contentText, forKey: "stringKey")
 shareDefaults?.synchronize()
```

Answer (score 26):

This is how you get the URL:

```
- (void)didSelectPost {
    NSExtensionItem *item = self.extensionContext.inputItems.firstObject;
    NSItemProvider *itemProvider = item.attachments.firstObject;
    if ([itemProvider hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier:@"public.url"]) {
        [itemProvider loadItemForTypeIdentifier:@"public.url"
                                        options:nil
                              completionHandler:^(NSURL *url, NSError *error) {
                                  NSString *urlString = url.absoluteString;
                                  // send url to server to share the link
                                  [self.extensionContext completeRequestReturningItems:@[]         
                                                                     completionHandler:nil];
                              }];
    }
}
```

Or in Swift:

```
override func didSelectPost() {
    if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem {
        if let itemProvider = item.attachments?.first as? NSItemProvider {
            if itemProvider.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
                itemProvider.loadItemForTypeIdentifier("public.url", options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) -> Void in
                    if let shareURL = url as? NSURL {
                        // send url to server to share the link
                    }
                    self.extensionContext?.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler:nil)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17):

There is one small change to this. In Chrome the public.url is in item 1, not item 0 of the attachements. Looping through to find it is better and will work on both chrome and safari.

```
if let item = extensionContext?.inputItems.first as? NSExtensionItem {
    if let attachments = item.attachments as? [NSItemProvider] {
        for attachment: NSItemProvider in attachments {
            if attachment.hasItemConformingToTypeIdentifier("public.url") {
                attachment.loadItemForTypeIdentifier("public.url", options: nil, completionHandler: { (url, error) in
                    if let shareURL = url as? NSURL {
                        // Do stuff with your URL now. 
                    }
                    self.extensionContext?.completeRequestReturningItems([], completionHandler:nil)
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should the attachment in the above example contain a com.apple.property-list? I can't seem o figure this one out. Using the code above I am not getting the URL. The completionHandler doesn't get executed because there doesn't seem to be a "public.url" in the com.apple.property-list

Comment: If you're having trouble getting your completion block to run, try replacing "loadItem" with "loadItemAsync"